# Ayuda con consulta SQL Oracle 11g

Tags: sql, oracle-11g

Necesito realizar dos consultas en sql, pero estoy estancado en una parte, les explico.

La primera consulta me solicitan lo siguiente:

> Se desea Conocer por cliente:  El total de facturas realizadas en el  mes, el valor total de las compras realizadas en el mes, el valor de la mínima factura, el valor de la máxima factura y el valor promedio de las compras realizadas en el mes; la consulta debe mostrar, ID cliente, nombre y apellido del cliente, el total de facturas del cliente, la factura con menor valor, la factura con mayor valor por último el promedio del total del valor de las facturas.

Ahora, estoy enfrascado en que el agrupamiento no lo está haciendo correctamente, sin eso, no sé siquiera como hacer la verificación de la factura con menor valor, la con mayor ni el promedio de estas facturas.

La consulta que llevo hecha es la siguiente:

```
    SELECT CI.ID_CLIENTE, CONCAT(CONCAT(CI.CLI_NOMBRE, ' '), CI.CLI_APELLIDO) AS "NOMBRE CLIENTE", 
COUNT(FA.ID_FACTURA) AS "CANTIDAD FACTURAS", SUM(DF.FAC_PRECIO_TOTAL)
FROM CLIENTE CI
INNER JOIN FACTURA FA ON FA.ID_CLIENTE = CI.ID_CLIENTE
INNER JOIN DETALLE_FACTURA DF ON DF.ID_FACTURA = FA.ID_FACTURA 
group by CI.ID_CLIENTE, CONCAT(CONCAT(CI.CLI_NOMBRE, ' '), CI.CLI_APELLIDO), FA.ID_FACTURA
ORDER BY CI.ID_CLIENTE ASC;
```

Pero esta hace el conteo de las facturas mal, les mostraré:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero eso está mal, en la tabla de facturas, solo los dos primero clientes (1 y 2) tienen tresfacturas, los otros solo tienen dos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y si solo lo agrupo por cliente me muestra así:

```
SELECT CI.ID_CLIENTE, CONCAT(CONCAT(CI.CLI_NOMBRE, ' '), CI.CLI_APELLIDO) AS "NOMBRE CLIENTE", 
COUNT(FA.ID_FACTURA) AS "CANTIDAD FACTURAS"
FROM CLIENTE CI
INNER JOIN FACTURA FA ON FA.ID_CLIENTE = CI.ID_CLIENTE
INNER JOIN DETALLE_FACTURA DF ON DF.ID_FACTURA = FA.ID_FACTURA 
group by CI.ID_CLIENTE, CONCAT(CONCAT(CI.CLI_NOMBRE, ' '), CI.CLI_APELLIDO)
ORDER BY CI.ID_CLIENTE ASC;
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No sé entonces cómo hacerlo, la verdad ya llevo enfrascado cerca de una hora en esta consulta que de seguro es una bobada :/

El Modelo Entidad-Relación es el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Puedes intentar realizando el counter dentro del from, para luego mandarlo a llamar por cada registro.

```
SELECT ID_CLIENTE, COUNTER FROM 
(SELECT CI.ID_CLIENTE, COUNT(FA.ID_FACTURA) AS COUNTER
FROM CLIENTE CI 
INNER JOIN FACTURA FA ON FA.ID_CLIENTE = CI.ID_CLIENTE
GROUP BY FA.ID_FACTURA, CI.ID_CLIENTE);
```

Puedes agregarle los detalles adicionales que requiere la solicitud.